# How to manage number of display courses in frontend?

Tags: moodle

I have Moodle website and I Installed new theme , What I need is How can I manage numbers on the display courses in front-end as the below URL display 3 courses in each row .

https://preview.themeforest.net/item/space-moodle-template/full_screen_preview/22579922?_ga=2.218178714.2021572415.1563651414-1811064317.1562426358

Answer (score 0):

You may change the amount of courses that are displayed in the frontpage by changing the Moodle setting `frontpagecourselimit` (as an admin). But keep in mind that it is entirely possible that the theme you mentioned overrides the frontpage renderer in a way that ignores that settings.